# Using JS (In FF-Pentadactyl), how to get a handle to site content like media players?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, vimperator

Using the Firefox Web Console (which can be brought up with control shift k ) I can easily access things like flowplayers.

```
jwplayer().play(), for example
```

The console even offers autocompletion suggestions for it.
What does the console do to be in that kind of, for my lack of words and knowledge, namespace?
I tried things like

```
content.document.getElementsByName('flvplayer').item(0)
```

Using Pentadactyls JS intepreter (accessed with :js)
This does seem to give me the player handle, or at least it prints out a `<html:object>` which corresponds to it.
Appending a .play() to it doesn't work, though. It's not a function.

What do I need to do to emulate the Web-Consoles way of doing it?

I realize that this might be a very spoonfeedy question, so if that is not acceptable then I'd still appreciate to get pointed into directions where I could possibly discover the solution myself by reading.

I tried searching for it myself but the terms seem to be quite ambiguous and I usually get results with people talking about their own sites, with scripts running inside of that 'namespace', not from outside like I am trying to do.
(Unless I am wrong about the concepts of inside and outside here.)

Cheers~~

Comment: why "jwplayer" in the first paragraph and "flvplayer" in the second paragraph? are they the same thing or different things? "jwplayer" is a function but "flvplayer" is an element?

Comment: [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/891648/how-do-i-run-a-pages-javascript-function/) look similar.

Answer (score 1):

The following command works for me; it defines the command `ypl` which 
plays the YouTube video on the page

```
command! ypl open javascript:(function()
    {content.document.getElementById('movie_player').playVideo()})()
```

Another example: this defines the `ytr` command which takes an integer argument and moves the current time position of the video by that amount in seconds

```
command! -nargs=1 ytr open javascript:(function(){var vid = 
    content.document.getElementById('movie_player'); vid.seekTo(vid.getCurrentTime() + 
    (<args>), true)})()
```

I hope that helps a bit. When I wrote those a while ago I may have tried `:js` and if it didn't work used `:open javascript:...`.